# "Incorrect Padding error" while decoding b64 but downloads corrupt excel files

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, base64

I am working on a file upload and download functionality and I have been trying to resolve a issue I got which is "Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (35125) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4". So I searched online which suggests me to changes the base64 syntax in code.

Before
base64.b64decode(data)
After
base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)

It worked and file gets uploaded.

But when I download the uploaded file I got a corrupt excel file xlsx, which could not be opened.

How can I resolve this issue?